# Align items with justify content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the next code:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(1)::after,
.menu li:nth-of-type(2)::after,
.menu li:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f111";
  display: inline-block;
  color: #8f81ca;
  font-size: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='menu'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</div>
```

I want to align all items with `justify-content:space-between`, but the dots don't align in the middle of each item, they stay near text. So, who knows how to align all elements using the same construction?

Comment: The dots are inside of the `li` element, which is already aligned with space-between.

Comment: because "dot" is not an item, its a part of your `li`...

Comment: You should understand how "::after" pseudo works. It creates a child element not a sibling element

Comment: Try to write HTML with valid markup. you have some list items without "ul" tag,
 It's not valid markup at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) to make the dots part of the flex container and `justify-content` will work as intended.

You can also simplify your CSS using `:not()`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display:contents;
}

.menu li:not(:last-child)::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f111";
  color: #8f81ca;
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class='menu'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Another solution is to adjust some flex properties to achieve this. The trick to make sure the pseudo element fill all the space between text and you center the dot inside.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  
}
ul li {
 list-style:none;
}
ul li:not(:last-child) {
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  
  outline:1px solid yellow;/*to illustrate*/
}

.menu li:not(:last-child)::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f111";
  color: #8f81ca;
  flex-grow:1;
  font-size:5px;
  text-align:center;
  
  outline:1px solid pink;/*to illustrate*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class='menu'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because "dot" is not a separate item, it's inside your `li` item. What you can do is to take separate `li` for "dots"

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dot::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f111";
  display: inline-block;
  color: #8f81ca;
  font-size: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='menu'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li class="dot"></li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li class="dot"></li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li class="dot"></li>
  <li>Four</li>
</div>
```